# Как сделать проверку get запроса?

Tags: php, rest

Как сделать проверку get запроса на совпадение с тем что находится в бд? И если данные которые пришли в запросе совпадают с теми что в бд значит всё ок а если не совпадают значит всё плохо.

Вот что у меня получилось но при отправке get запроса получаю `Failed` в ответ

```
<?php
// необходимые HTTP-заголовки
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");

if(isset($_GET['name'])){

    require_once __DIR__.'/boot.php';
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $get = null;

    $stmt = pdo()->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `get_package_name`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $get = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $get['name'];

    if($name == $get) {
        echo json_encode("OK");
    } else {
        echo json_encode("NO");
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode("Failed");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Failed` выводится если не определен `$_GET['name']`. Что показывает `print_r($_GET)`?

Comment: Пустой массив возвращает

Comment: Теперь следует понять почему так. Каким образом вызывается этот скрипт?

Comment: Через postman отправляю запрос на страницу

Comment: Это точно GET-запрос? Может это все-таки POST-запрос? Точно ли указаны нужные параметры запроса?

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: Ну ты присылаешь в body json. О каком `GET['name']` может идти речь? GET-параметр передается в строке запроса: `test.php?name=myname` Можно это либо прямо в строке с урлом прописать, либо на вкладке params.

Comment: Тогда я получаю ошибку 500 что страница https://sssss.ru/test3/test.php?name=com.buratinoapps.faucet не найдена

Comment: Откуда взялся ssss, если на картинке какой-то xmonitoring?

Comment: Это я здесь специально написал

Comment: Ну теперь значит надо открыть логи и понять причину 500-й ошибки.